# VBA auto filter - the difference between two approaches

Tags: excel, vba

I try to understand the difference between this approach (the way my boss wanted me to do it):

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
        "=some*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:= _
        "=else*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=else2", Operator:=xlAnd

Dim i As Long
i = 0
Do
i = i + 1
Loop While Cells(i, 20) <> ""
Cells(i, 20).Select
End Sub
```

and the way I wanted to auto filter it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
        "=some*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:= _
        "=else*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=else2", Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

When running a macro I do not see any change, so I guess I do not really understand what this lines do...

```
Dim i As Long
i = 0
Do
i = i + 1
Loop While Cells(i, 20) <> ""
Cells(i, 20).Select
```

Any suggestions on this matter?

Comment: I think after `AutoFilter` your boss is *trying to select the blank cell in `20th` column*. That is leave the cursor at that cell. But in your case the cursor will be at the cell it was initially at before running the code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was so simple! But I just could not have captured it. I knew it was looking for an empty cell but was kind of expecting a "bigger" difference between two approaches. Cheers!